# Show selected images, webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show an image selected by the user from the list, but I do not see anything on the screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .center {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <p>Images:</p>
  <select id="ImSelect" size="6" onchange "getvalue()">
    <option value="LB_1_000561">LB_1_000561</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000562">LB_1_000562</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000563">LB_1_000563</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000564">LB_1_000564</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000565">LB_1_000565</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000566">LB_1_000566</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000567">LB_1_000567</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000568">LB_1_000568</option>
    <option value="LB_1_000569">LB_1_000569</option>
  </select>

  <div class="container" id="x"></div>

  <script>
    function getvalue() {
      var value_ = document.getElementById("ImSelect").value;
      img.src = "Images/" + value_ + ".jpg";
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      var src = document.getElementById("x");
      src.appendChild(img);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're setting `img.src` before creating `var img`.

Comment: Missing a `=` in `onchange "getvalue()"`

Comment: It may be helpful to open the console when debugging. You would probably see at least one error.

Comment: @ryan28561 There wouldn't actually be any errors in this case, evidenced by running the snippet. The function with the errors is never called due to a typo in the HTML.

Comment: @j08691 I believe that edit may have removed a fair bit of other HTML jankiness, by the way. As Scott points out below, the original HTML doesn't have a `<head>` element.

Comment: @j08691 You really shouldn't have made that edit because you altered the incorrectness of the HTML in the original code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus and Tyler Feel free to make any rollbacks you need. Head issue aside, which I doubt is the cause of any issues, the only code change was a removed space in `onchange"getvalue()"` which was caused by the stack snippet tidy button.

Comment: I elected to roll it back and just drop all the HTML in a snippet to keep it runnable but also reflect the original issues. Someone stomp that out if I dun' messed up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because nothing ever calls your `getValue` function. You're `onchange` needs an `=` after it, as in `onchange="getvalue()"`. [But, you shouldn't be setting up event handlers in HTML in the first place.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) You need that function to be called whenever you make a selection in your `select`, so a `change` event handler needs to be set up for it and that handler should be set up in JavaScript.

Also, you are trying to set the `src` of your image before you've created it. You need to swap those two lines.

Additionally, you don't have a `head` section to your document and your `style` element should go in there, rather than in `body`.

Finally, your code will create a new image and append it to the document every time a selection is made, so you could wind up with many images showing. If you only want one image showing (the most recently selected one), then instead of creating a new image and appending it to the document, just create a static `img` element in the page, where you want it, but don't set its `src` in the HTML. Then, all your JavaScript needs to do is access that pre-existing image and set its `src` instead of generating a new one an appending it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .center {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    img { 
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>   
    <p>Images:</p>
    <select id="ImSelect"  size="6">
      <option value="LB_1_000561">LB_1_000561</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000562">LB_1_000562</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000563">LB_1_000563</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000564">LB_1_000564</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000565">LB_1_000565</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000566">LB_1_000566</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000567">LB_1_000567</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000568">LB_1_000568</option>
      <option value="LB_1_000569">LB_1_000569</option> 
    </select>
    
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Each new image will display in this one elmeent -->
      <img id="target" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <script>
    let select = document.getElementById("ImSelect");
    let target = document.getElementById("target");
    
    // Set up the change event hanlder in JavaScript, not in HTML
    select.addEventListener("change", getvalue);
    
    function getvalue() { 
      // Just update the src of the pre-existing img element
      target.src = "Images/" + select.value + ".jpg";
      target.alt = target.src; // Just to show something on the screen for demo
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please edit Code to have only one Image on the page.